# Error parsing xml from file but not as string? Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xmltodict

I am trying to use `xml2dict` to parse a large number of xml files so that i can turn them into dataframes, however, when I try and parse the actual xml files I get the error:

```
"ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 5"
```

This error is exactly the same for all the xml files, including "line 1, column 5", which differ considerably in length but are all the same in structure.

When I try to copy the contents of the xml file as a string in python the parsing with xml2dict works perfectly. For example:

```
xmlstr ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document id="DDI-DrugBank.d200">
    <sentence id="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s0" text="Co-administration of probenecid with acyclovir has been shown to increase the mean half-life and the area under the concentration-time curve.">
        <entity id="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s0.e0" charOffset="21-30"
            type="drug" text="probenecid"/>
        <entity id="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s0.e1" charOffset="37-45"
            type="drug" text="acyclovir"/>
        <pair id="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s0.p0" e1="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s0.e0"
            e2="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s0.e1" ddi="true" type="mechanism"/>
    </sentence>
    <sentence id="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s1" text="Urinary excretion and renal clearance were correspondingly reduced."/>
    <sentence id="DDI-DrugBank.d200.s2" text="The clinical effects of this combination have not been studied."/>
</document>"""

import xmltodict as x2d

nestdict1 = x2d.parse('Train/DrugBank/Aciclovir_ddi.xml')

nestdict2 = x2d.parse(xmlstr)
```

In the above example `nestdict1` throws the error while `nestdict2` is fine despite `xmlstr` being a direct copy and paste from the file `'Train/DrugBank/Aciclovir_ddi.xml'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a file object, not a string which is the filename.

From the [docs](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/master/xmltodict.py#L192):

```
In [4]:print(xmltodict.parse.__doc__)
Parse the given XML input and convert it into a dictionary.

    `xml_input` can either be a `string` or a file-like object.
```

So, create a file descriptor like:

```
fd = open("Train/DrugBank/Aciclovir_ddi.xml")
```

And then pass it to the parse method:

```
x2d.parse(fd)
```